# Add button column to datatable

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable

I am trying to insert a button column into a datatable but it says that its an error. Any help pleasE?

```
        ButtonColumn col = new ButtonColumn();
        col.CommandName = "select";
        col.ButtonType = ButtonColumnType.LinkButton;
        col.HeaderText = "Edit";
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: 1. you really not adding to `datatable` you need to add it to datagrid. 2. Mind to share what kind of error you getting or we need to guess?

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add Buttoncolumn in DataTable its wired ...thats not possible at all...

The **DataTable DataColumn  DataType** property supports the following base .NET Framework data types:

1. Boolean
2. Byte
3. Char
4. DateTime
5. Decimal
6. Double
7. Int16
8. Int32
9. Int64
10. SByte
11. Single
12. String
13. TimeSpan
14. UInt16
15. UInt32
16. UInt64

Sample code to add coplumn

```
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Customers"); 
DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(Int32));
workCol.AllowDBNull = true;
```

Comment: I think OP actually trying to add column to datagrid-datasource is datatable so that's why :)

Comment: @Reniuz - i m wating for the update from op side so that i can update my answer according to that...

Comment: I'm missing `Byte[]` in the above list. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can add a `button` only on `DataGrid` not `DataTable`.